# type clientv3.Config has no field or method Username

Tags: go, etcd3

the code is:

```
import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "time"

    "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
)
func main(){
    ...
    config := clientv3.Config{}
    config.Username = u.username
    ...
}
```

go.mod file

```
module github.com/xxx

go 1.17

require (

    github.com/coreos/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible // indirect
    go.etcd.io/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible // indirect
)
```

It fails with this message:

```
config.Username undefined (type clientv3.Config has no field or method Username)
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem?what's the difference between github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3 and  go.etcd.io/etcd？

Comment: the 'coreos' was the original package which is now  depreciated, now use the official package https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3, try running go clean to clean the cache

Comment: It‘s useful.thank you

Answer (score 1):

`go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3` and `go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3` are, somewhat confusingly, distinct packages that both use the package name `clientv3`.

The [`client/v3.Config`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3#Config) type has the `Username` field you expect, so perhaps you can update your code to import that package instead of the other one?

```golang
import (
    …
    "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3"
)
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/2SK2FUNxWs9)

---

`github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3` was an older name for the package from the `github.com/coreos/etcd` repo before they adopted Go modules. When they moved to modules, they changed the canonical import path to `go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3`, but (through some quirks of the Go module system) a hybrid of the old and new paths can still be resolved, using the code from the old path but served from the new URL. You probably want to use only the new canonical path.